# Database independent random order in NHibernate

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate

I have a query which uses code like:

```
criteria.AddOrder(
    Order.Asc(
        Projections.SqlFunction(
           new StandardSQLFunction("NEWID"), 
           new NHType.GuidType(), 
           new IProjection[0])));
```

The purpose is to get a random ordering. I run this against an SQL server, but I would also like to run it against an SQLite, since we use this for testing. SQLite does not support `NEWID()` but has `Random` instead. Is it possible to write the code (or configure) such that the same query will work against both databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way to do this is to create two custom dialects. Have each one implement a `random` function differently:

```
public class MyMsSqlDialect : MsSql2012Dialect
{
    protected override void RegisterFunctions()
    {
        base.RegisterFunctions();
        RegisterFunction("random", new StandardSQLFunction("NEWID", NHibernateUtil.Guid));
    }
}

public class MySqliteDialect : SQLiteDialect
{
    protected override void RegisterFunctions()
    {
        base.RegisterFunctions();
        RegisterFunction("random", new StandardSQLFunction("random", NHibernateUtil.Guid));
    }
}
```

Now, the following query should work fine in either database:

```
criteria.AddOrder(
    Order.Asc(
        Projections.SqlFunction("random", NHibernateUtil.Guid)));
```

Note that this is cheating a bit. `random` doesn't return a `Guid` in the Sqlite flavor, but since NHibernate doesn't need that information to do the `ORDER BY`, nothing should go wrong. I would consider calling it `random_order` or something to make it clear that this is only for ordering.